# Terraform combing multiple sets of resources in for_each

Tags: foreach, terraform

we are busy setting up our Snowflake DB with Terraform. We are trying to have a `for_each` loop for several sets of objects.

EDIT: We are trying to set up database USAGE for a set of roles, where the roles were set up with a `for_each` loop

Something like:

```
resource "snowflake_database_grant" "grant_db_usage_to_roles" {
  for_each = concat([snowflake_role.transform_roles], [snowflake_role.read_all_role], [snowflake_role.load_roles["SRC"]])
  database_name = snowflake_database.database.name
  privilege = "USAGE"
  roles = [each.value.name]
  with_grant_option = false
}
```

In the above case the `transform_roles` contain a few objects while the `read_all_role` and `load_role["SRC"]` are only one role.

We tried concat, merge, map but no luck. Just missing some good guidance on the different types and what happens under the hood.

If anyone can guide here on the right function to combine the objects that would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly are `snowflake_role.transform_roles` and the other data used in `contact`? Whats their format and content? " no luck" is not specific. What exactly is happening. Any errors?

Answer (score 0):

When I tried your code I'm getting an error:
`The given "for_each" argument value is unsuitable: the "for_each" argument must be a map, or set of strings, and you have provided a value of type tuple.`

The fix is simple just use `toset`

Here is the code I tried:

```hcl
terraform {
  required_providers {
    snowflake = {
      source = "Snowflake-Labs/snowflake"
      version = "0.33.1"
    }
  }
}

resource snowflake_role a {
  count   = 2
  name    = "role${count.index}"
  comment = "A role."
}

resource snowflake_role b {
  name    = "read role"
  comment = "A role."
}

resource snowflake_database_grant grant_db_usage_to_roles {
  for_each          = toset(concat([snowflake_role.a], [snowflake_role.b]))
  database_name     = "test"
  privilege         = "USAGE"
  roles             = [each.value.name]
  with_grant_option = false
}
```

You can read more about for_each here:
https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/for_each#basic-syntax

Comment: Thanks a lot. This learned me that I was actually looking in the wrong place. My goal was to grant access to a set of roles. I achieved that with the code below

`roles = concat([for role in snowflake_role.transform_roles : role.name], [for role in snowflake_role.load_roles : role.name])`

Thanks a lot for facilitating that